# How to copy a string and paste a substring in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, command

Found this on the interwebs:

```
(defun clipboard/set (astring)
  "Copy a string to clipboard"
   (with-temp-buffer
    (insert astring)
    (clipboard-kill-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

I want to make it interactive, run the string through substring, and then copy it to the clipboard

```
(defun clipboard/set (astring)
  "Copy a string to clipboard"
(interactive)
(let (bstring (substring astring -11)))   
(with-temp-buffer
    (insert bstring)
    (clipboard-kill-region (point-min) (point-max))))
```

How would one do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell `interactive` how to populate the arguments:

```
(interactive "sAstring: ")
```

Also, the syntax of `let` is different, it starts with a list of lists of variables and values, i.e.

```
(let ((bstring (substring astring -11)))
;    ^^
```

i.e.

```
(defun clipboard/set (astring)
  "Copy a string to clipboard"
  (interactive "sAstring: ")
  (let ((bstring (substring astring -11)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert bstring)
      (clipboard-kill-region (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

and close it at the very end.

Comment: Thanks. I've been experimenting with this a bit and getting the same error, which happens here also:                                                                                (wrong-number-of-arguments (lambda nil "Copy a string to clipboard" (interactive "sAstring: ") (let ((bstring (substring astring -11)))) (let ((temp-buffer (generate-new-buffer " *temp*"))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer temp-buffer) (unwind-protect (progn (insert bstring) (clipboard-kill-region (point-min) (point-max))) (and (buffer-name temp-buffer) (kill-buffer temp-buffer)))))) 1)

Comment: Check the update, I included the whole command. It runs for me, but I have no idea what it should do.

Comment: It works! (defun paste/substring (astring)
  "Copy a string to clipboard"
(interactive "sAstring: ")
(with-temp-buffer
    (insert (substring astring -11))
    (clipboard-kill-region (point-min) (point-max))))